# Mask input for number - percent

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can create a mask input for number that have percent by jQuery? Do I make input just accept until three numbers and put percent sign after numbers while user finished typing(`keyup`)?

**I don't use plugins.**

Example:
**1%** Or **30%** Or **99%** Or **100%** Or **200%**

```
<input name="number" class="num_percent">
```

Comment: Why not put the percent sign after the input field and save that part of the hassle?

Comment: Why do you need the percent sign if you know the number represents a percent? Just take the input without a percent sign and divide it by 100.

Comment: I want put percent sign that user to know this number is a real number. How is it?

Comment: @JimBo, you don't need the user to enter a percent sign, though. Tell us a bit more of what you're trying to do. Post more of your page.

Comment: I mean put a (permanent, static) percent sign next to the input field instead of painfully adding it into it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're better off not using JavaScript for this.  Besides the problems that come with using `onkeyup` for detecting text input, you also have the hassle of parsing the resulting string back to a number in your client/server scripts.  If you want the percent sign to look integrated, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="percentInput">
    <input type="text" name="number" class="num_percent">
    <span>%</span>
</div>
```

```
.percentInput { position:relative; }
.percentInput span { position: absolute; right: 4px; top:2px; }
.num_percent { text-align: right; padding-right: 12px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BvVq4/

I'm rushing slightly, so you may have to tweak the styles to get it to look right cross-browser.  At least it gives you the general idea.

Comment: in the fiddle there is a maxlength property but not here... so look at the jsfiddle.

Comment: Oh, that is _very_ nice. Future work would be to add an `onclick` handler to the `span` that focuses the `input`, and add a numeric-only validation to the `input`.

Comment: That is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I've stayed with input number, moved the percentage char and then modified its position according to the length of the input (the amount of digits).

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="100"> //chose 100 only for the sake of the example
<span class="percentage-char">%</span>
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  width: 55px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size:18px;
}
.percentage-char {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32px; // default position - in this case 100
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 18px; 
}
.one-digit { //position of the '%' when input is 0-9
  left: 13px;
}
.two-digits{ //position of the '%' when input is 10-99
  left: 24px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(":input").change(function() { //listening to changes on input
   if ($(this).val() < 10) { //adding and removing the classes
        $('.percentage-char').removeClass('two-digits');
        $('.percentage-char').addClass('one-digit');
   } else if ($(this).val() > 9 && $(this).val() < 100) {
        $('.percentage-char').addClass('two-digits');
   } else {
        $('.percentage-char').removeClass('one-digit two-digits');
   }
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/16845/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setPercentageMask() {
    let input = $('.percent');
    input.mask('##0,00', {reverse: true});
    input.bind("change keyup", function() {
        isBetweenPercentage($(this));
    });
}

function isBetweenPercentage(input) {
    let myNumber = (input.val()) ? parseFloat(input.val()) : 0;
    (myNumber.isBetween(0, 100.00)) ? myNumber : input.val('100,00');
}

if (typeof(Number.prototype.isBetween) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.isBetween = function(min, max, notBoundaries) {
            var between = false;
            if (notBoundaries) {
                if ((this < max) && (this > min)) between = true;
            } else {
                if ((this <= max) && (this >= min)) between = true;
            }
            return between;
    }
}

setPercentageMask();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input name="text" class="percent">
```