# Is there a way to add percentage sign to t-input while keeping the type of the input number?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm using VueTailwinds in my FE.
Is there a way to append percentage sign to the value within the input field while keeping the type of the field number/numeric?

For instance,
something similar to what the vue-number-format package offers.

Comment: The solution could be a simple HTML/CSS trick, making the parent look like the input field and adding the `%` sign simply as text in a span: [Mask input for number - percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933505/mask-input-for-number-percent)